# The integral $\int_{-1}^2 |e^x-1|\mathrm{d}x.$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the integral
$$\int_{-1}^2 |e^x-1|\mathrm{d}x.$$
Been stuck on this for a while, seems really easy for some reason but can't get the correct answer

Comment: The first step is to get rid of the absolute value function. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: From $-1$ to $0$ we have $e^x-1\le 0$, and after that it is $\ge 0$.

Comment: @LordSoth absolutely none at first, got it now. is it just knowing/graphing that the function is negative/postive at different values?

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}\int_{-1}^2|e^x-1|dx&=\int_{-1}^0(1-e^x)dx+\int_0^2(e^x-1)dx\\
&=x-e^x\big|_{-1}^0+e^x-x\big|_0^2=e^{-1}+e^2-3\end{align}

Comment: grazie mille frate! that's an easy way to write it out

Comment: "An" easy way to write it out? That´s the complete answer...

Comment: i know.. i'm not too great with changing absolutes to non absolutes, that's what i meant.

Comment: Short and sweet, Sami!